# C# add custom event each time a interface method is called

Tags: c#, .net

Let say we have this interface, provided by a third party DLL and we cannot change the code :

```
public interface ICustomService
{
    void Method1(string param1, Guid param2);
    Guid Method2(string param1);
    void Method3(string param1, Guid param2);
    void Method4(string param1, Guid param2);
    CustomClass1 Method4(CustomClass4 param1);
    CustomClass2 Method5(string param1, Guid param2, CustomClass4 param3);
    CustomClass3 Method6(string param1);
    void Method7(CustomClass5 param1);
}
```

Then, when the interface is instanciate and each time we call one of its methods. I would like to know if it possible to raise an "event" that will inherit from the context of the call, in order to do some extra logic before calling the method itself.

For example (pseudo code):

```
// Instanciate the service
ICustomService service = connection.CustomServiceObject;

// Call Method1
service.Method1("param1", Guid.NewGuid()); 

// When Method1 is called, to be redirected to a piece of code like that 
public void EventPieceOfCode(SomethingLikeAContext context)
{
    // DO YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE. 
    
    
    // Let the intial logic happens
    context.OriginalLogic();
}
```

Sorry if it's not clear, I don't know if it's feasible that's why I can present you only my mind :)

Thx

Comment: So you want to "intercept" each call and do extra things before the real one?

Comment: It is not possible with default C#. It is possible with AOP solutions like PostSharp, but that adds a whole extra level of complexity. Maybe try explaining **why** you (think) you need this, as it's possible it could be an X-Y problem.

Comment: The whole point of an interface is that it defines nothing about the implementation of the member, only that it exists.  If you want the type to define the implementation of the member it needs to be a non-interface type.

Comment: @Alejandro yes !

Comment: @Servy ok so let say that instead of an Interface it will be directly a class itself... It would be possible ? (but a class from a DLL for which I cannot change the code)

Comment: @IanKemp I need to do this because I have hundreds of methods of ICustomService used on an existing code, and I have to do the same logic for all the methods... I would like to avoid doing it for hundreds but simply once with the "mechanism" asked here. :)

Comment: @MarcAlves Sure, then the implementation of all of the members fires an event and then calls out to a protected member to do the rest of the implementation.

Comment: @Servy Yes ! Any example on how to do that thing ? :)

Comment: @MarcAlves As already stated, there's unfortunately no way with default C# to do this. If there are many methods, your best bet is to write a tool that generates code that wraps them with a call to your custom interceptor method - or use PostSharp as already suggested.

Comment: @IanKemp Thx, Servy seems to have an idea in the condition I dont deal with the interface but the class itself (possible in my scenario). Waiting from him to have more details :)

Comment: @MarcAlves What about that do you not understand how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "proxy" class that implement the very same interface and adds the required logic and then forwards its calls to the real implementation. Something like this will do:

```
public class CustomServiceProxy : ICustomService
{
    private readonly ICustomService service;

    public CustomServiceProxy(ICustomService service) {
        this.service = service;
   }

    public void Method1(string param1, Guid param2) {
        //Add custom code here

        //Forward the call to the real implementation
        this.service.Method1(param1, param2);

        //Add custom code here
    }

    //For value-returning methods, pass the return value back
    public Guid Method2(string param1) {
        //Add custom code here

        //Forward the call and keep the return value
        Guid returnValue = this.service.Method2(param1);

        //Add custom code here and possibly manipulate return value

        //Forward back the return value
        return returnValue;
    }

    //Repeat for each and every method on the interface
}
```

And now when you need an `ICustomService` you actually instantiate your own proxy, passing to it the real service instance. All other code that depends on the same interface will just continue working in the very same way, you only need to change the instantiation, and if you already have it centralized, that's the only place you need to modify.

BTW, it's a similar technique to what allow ORMs to implement lazy loading, or what test frameworks use to assert on calls made to dependencies.

Comment: This one seems to be a good option since for existing code I have to only change the initial instanciation of the original interface by using this custom one and because the method defintions are the same it should be ok. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking Aspect-Oriented Programming. C# is Object-Oriented, a different paradigm; but that doesn't mean it's impossible.

Take a look at the decorator and proxy design patterns; [MSDN has an article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/february/aspect-oriented-programming-aspect-oriented-programming-with-the-realproxy-class):

> AOP implementations use some common techniques:
>
> - Adding source code using a pre-processor, such as the one in C++.
> - Using a post-processor to add instructions on the compiled binary code.
> - Using a special compiler that adds the code while compiling.
> - Using a code interceptor at run time that intercepts execution and adds the desired code.
>
> In the .NET Framework, the most commonly used of these techniques are post-processing and code interception. The former is the technique used by PostSharp (postsharp.net) and the latter is used by dependency injection (DI) containers such as Castle DynamicProxy (bit.ly/JzE631) and Unity (unity.codeplex.com). These tools usually use a design pattern named Decorator or Proxy to perform the code interception.

Implementing AOP in C# isn't a simple task, as you can see. A more OO approach would be to wrap your 3rd Party library in your own class. Or, if it suits your needs, [create an extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: Thx for your response Connor Low. As you said AOP is not simple and your propostion of OO approach seems to looks like the one of Alejandro. :)